# How to show embedded resource images from external library set from code behind?

Tags: winui-3, winui

I have a common library `foo.common` with some *.pngs stored as `Embedded Resource` or `Resource`.
Now I would like to show them in my `foo.ui` `WinUI3` application.

I can't get any further at the moment. I've tried the following things without success...

```xml
<Image Source="ms-appx://Foo.Common/Assets/Images/foo.png"/>
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Foo.Common/Assets/Images/foo.png"/>
```

```cs
new Image
{
    Source = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx://Foo.Common/Assets/Images/foo.png") }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To get the `Embedded Resource` from code behind, you can use this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37010020/6229375) solution. To convert the `stream` afterwards into an `ImageSource`, you can use one of the following extension methods.

```cs
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static async Task<BitmapImage> ToBitmapImageAsync(this Stream stream)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
            memStream.Position = 0;

            bitmap.SetSource(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static async Task<SvgImageSource> ToSvgImageSourceAsync(this Stream stream)
    {
        var bitmap = new SvgImageSource();
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
            memStream.Position = 0;

            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

---

I'm actually still stuck how to get it working in `xaml`.

Comment: If you have put a foo.png file in the root of the project (and set Visual Studio Build Action to "Content"), the you can get its path like this:  `new ResourceManager().MainResourceMap.GetValue("Files/foo.png").ValueAsString`

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to load the image from a `resource` / `embedded resource`. 

Comment: I don't think support for embedded resource is built in winui3 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/mrtcore/mrtcore-overview). ms-appx points to MainResourceMap. If the app is unpackaged, you can always write files and load from them. If the app is packaged (contained), you can always build ImageSource from your streams (like you do) and bind these in XAML or code.